# Is there anyway to give anonymous users UserProperties?

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to save user-input without asking for unnecessary permissions

I'm working on a simple web app on google apps script that collects the user's name as they check in to a library, puts them in a specific spreadsheet, and remembers that name for the next time they login. When I publish as myself, it works fine and gives even anonymous people a chance to check into my personal spreadsheet, however the name remembered is shared between all users because it is set to launch as me. When I publish as a regular user visiting the web page, it works for me who has already granted the app access, but it shows a lot of errors and tells users I need access to their spreadsheets when I really don't.

These are my two main functions for gathering and posting the info

```
function login(name, id, purpose) {
var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();  
var d = new Date();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT-4", "LLLL dd, yyyy")
var time = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT-4", "hh:mm aaa")

cache.removeAll(["login status"]);
cache.put("login status",  name + "|" + id + "|" + "inLib", 31536000);

var blob = name + " | " + id + " | " + purpose + " | " +  date + " | "+ time;
record("sign_in", blob);  
Logger.log(d);

}

function record(command, info) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("#myspreadsheetid");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var sheetInfo = info.split(" | ");

var id = sheetInfo[1];

if (command == "sign_in") {
sheet.appendRow(sheetInfo);
}

if (command == "sign_out") {    

for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){

Logger.log(data[i][1]);      
Logger.log(id);

if(data[i][1] == id){

sheet.getRange("F"+(i+1).toString()).setValue(sheetInfo[3]);

}

} 

}

return sheet

}
```

I expected the caches to be different for each user without asking for extra sheets access, but that's not the case

Comment: Have you considered using [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) instead of Cache Service? I believe it goes more in line with what you're trying to accomplish. You can take a look at the [reference documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/)

Comment: You can try [getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTemporaryActiveUserKey()) & store this value under `UserProperties` but do please remember that this key rotates every 30 days and is unique to the script.

Comment: @AMolina, I already tried that, but the same problem where everyone has the same properties because of the user being the same persists.

Comment: @SourabhChoraria I'll look into it thanks